# string array as parameter to plpgsql procedure

Tags: plpgsql

Can some one guide me how to test this procedure. (code got compiled but dont know if it is correct or not).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_update_h( p_a_pkg_array CHARACTER VARYING [],p_u_pkg_array CHARACTER VARYING [] ,  inout out_error_code  TEXT , inout out_error_text  text )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

calling with

```
do
$$
DECLARE out_error_code TEXT;
DECLARE out_error_text TEXT;
BEGIN

CALL create_update_h(
    ['t','t','t']::CHARACTER VARYING [],[result1,result2,result3]::CHARACTER VARYING [],out_error_code::TEXT,out_error_text::TEXT);
RAISE NOTICE 'myvar1 = %', out_error_code;
        RAISE NOTICE 'mymsg1 = %', out_error_text;                                     
END;
$$
```

giving error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 9:  [t,t,t]::CHARACTER VARYING [],[result1,result2,result3]::CH...
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 162
```

I tried the above script to test the proc . Could somebody tell me how to call a proceudre that has 2 arrays as input.

Comment: try this syntax : `select '{hello,Hi,Bye}'::CHARACTER VARYING[]`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for array constructor in PostgreSQL is:

```
ARRAY[field, field ...]
```

The keyword `ARRAY` is mandatory

Comment: Thank you.  I modified  and now calling successfully.  But the values are not  getting inserted  in table. I am priinting the values that I passed. but after that the insert  is not happening.